# Finding the normal subgroups in a semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

Let the group $A=\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_{-1}\times\mathbb{Z}_{0}\times\mathbb{Z}_{1}\times\cdots$ with $\mathbb{Z}_{i}=\left\langle a_{i}\right\rangle $ and $\alpha:a_{i}\rightarrow a_{i+1}$ an automorphism of $A$. Consider the group $G=\left\langle \alpha\right\rangle \rtimes A$ (semidirect product). How can I find the normal subgroups of $G$ contained
in $A$?

Thanks!

Comment: What are $\;\Bbb Z_{-1}\;,\;\;\Bbb Z_0\;$ , etc.?

Comment: It's just an infinite sequence of copies of $\mathbb Z$, with $a_i$ a generator for $\mathbb Z_i$. I agree, confusing use of $\mathbb Z_i$.

Comment: It's right. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I wonder how you knew that before the OP answered.

Comment: $a_i$ wasn't specified as to meaning, so it seemed like the "most likely" definition, especially given the negative and zero coefficients, so that $\mathbb Z_n$ wouldn't have any of the usual meanings. Finally, $\alpha$ wouldn't be an automorphism of $A$ unless all of the $\mathbb Z_n$ were the same size. @Timbuc

Comment: Nice @ThomasAndrews. Thank you. +1

Comment: The better, more formal approach is to define $A$ as the set of all functions $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ under addition, and $\alpha(f)(n)=f(n-1)$.

Comment: What normal subgroups can you think of yourself? (It's good to show some indication that have thought about the problem a bit yourself.)